# Groovy: Why do I need to double escape square brackets?

Tags: groovy

Why doesn't this work?

```
"hello[world".split("\[")
```

and this does:

```
"hello[world".split("\\[")
```

Comment: Beside @Don Roby answer, if you use a groovy regex you can shortcut the double escapes using the `/\[/` syntax.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is actually two escapes in different contexts, due to the fact that the argument is a regular expression represented as a string.

The `[` has to be escaped because otherwise it would have a special meaning in the regular expression.  The escape for the regular expression would make it `\[`.  But then the `\` has to be escaped as it has special meaning in a string (for escaping and for representing characters by numeric value).

It can be much worse, as the `\` character is used for escaping in both contexts.  If you want to split by the `\` character, you have to escape it (`\\`) for the regular expression usage, but then you have two `\` characters, which both have to be escaped in string context.  The usage in the original string you are splitting would also need the escape if you're writing it as a constant, so the analogous split would look like:

```
"hello\\world".split("\\\\")
```

Answer (score 1):

Different versions of Groovy give different results.

For Groovy 1.1-BETA-1 and onwards,

```
assert "hello[world".split("\\[") == ["hello", "world"]
```

asserts OK, but Groovy 1.0 and before gives an assertion error.

```
assert "hello[world".split(/\[/) == ["hello", "world"]
```

asserts OK for all versions from 1.1-BETA-1 onwards, Groovy 1.0-jsr-01 to 1.0 gives an assertion error, while Groovy 1.0-beta-10 and before gives a lexical error.

```
"hello[world".split("\\[").each{println it}
```

for all versions of Groovy from 1.0-beta-5, and beta-3, prints

```
hello
world
```

but 1.0-beta-4 prints

```
[.]
[.]
hello
world
```