# Define fields by whitespace, quotes or parentheses in gawk

Tags: regex, awk, gawk

I have a text file with the following format:

```
RANDOM-WORD1 ==> "string with whitespaces" (string with whitespaces)
RANDOM-WORD2 ==> "another string" (and another)
RANDOM-WORD3 ==> "yet another string" (and another)
```

I want to define the `gawk` delimeters by:

- whitespaces
- quotes
- parentheses

For example, line 1:

```
$1: RANDOM-WORD1
$2: ==>
$3: "string with whitespaces"
$4: (string with whitespaces)
```

I have read `gawk`'s `FPAT` [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html) and I have written this:

```
FPAT = "([^[:blank:]]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")|(\([^)]+\))"
```

However, it does not work for the parentheses, as I get:

```
$1: RANDOM-WORD1
$2: ==>
$3: "string with whitespaces"
$4: (string
```

I've tried escaping the parentheses in the third clause, but it won't work either. I want to ignore any character that is not a `)` inside a pair of `( ... )`. I know for a fact that there won't be any nested parentheses.

NB: how can I also ignore the quotes/parentheses as field data? For example:

```
$1: RANDOM-WORD1
$2: ==>
$3: string with whitespaces
$4: string with whitespaces
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the parentheses, you need to escape them **twice**:

```
FPAT = "([^[:blank:]]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")|(\\([^\\)]+\\))"
```

To get rid of parentheses and quotes, use `substr`:

```
$3 = substr($3, 2, length($3) - 2);
$4 = substr($4, 2, length($4) - 2);
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I also found out the reason behind it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383643/groovy-why-do-i-need-to-double-escape-square-brackets ; is it a similar case?

Comment: @Adama see http://stackoverflow.com/a/36806066/1745001 for why you need to escape them twice. btw you can replace `[^[:blank:]]` with `\\S` since you're using gawk anyway.

Comment: @Adama In my understanding, `awk` interprets the string before invoking the regex processing engine. Now according to [the specifications](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html#tag_04_06_13_04), `\(` is not a valid escape sequence listed in the spec's table. That's also the reason why gawk displays the error "warning: escape sequence '\)' treated as plain ')'". The `\(` never makes it to the regex engine. To make that happen, you need to escape the backslash as \\, so that it will pass string processing and the regex engine gets to see `\(`.

Answer (score 1):

This `FPAT = "([^ ]+)|([(][^)]+[)])|(\"[^\"]+\")"` works for me. It uses the trick that inside `[ ]` the `(` and `)` do not need quoting.

Concerning your second question about stripping the quotes or the parenthesis, I have no better idea than adding an action like this:

```
{ for( i=1; i<= NF; i++ ) {
    b = substr( $i, 1, 1 );
    e = substr( $i, length( $i ), 1 );
    if( ( b == "\"" || b == "(" ) && (b == e) ) {
      $i = substr( $i,2 , length( $i ) - 2 )
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for your feedback. :) The "double escape is a bit more consistent with the other two clauses, so I'll go with that, but I'll definitely keep that trick as well.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use FPAT for this, as there's an order to your fields, not just a pattern. I'd use the 3rd arg to match() as it's simpler and more robust:

```
match($0,/(\S+)\s(\S+)\s"([^"]+)"\s\(([^)]+).*/,a)
```

e.g.:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/(\S+)\s(\S+)\s"([^"]+)"\s\(([^)]+).*/,a) { print; for (i=1; i in a; i++) printf "a[%d]: %s\n", i, a[i] }' file
RANDOM-WORD1 ==> "string with whitespaces" (string with whitespaces)
a[1]: RANDOM-WORD1
a[2]: ==>
a[3]: string with whitespaces
a[4]: string with whitespaces
RANDOM-WORD2 ==> "another string" (and another)
a[1]: RANDOM-WORD2
a[2]: ==>
a[3]: another string
a[4]: and another
RANDOM-WORD3 ==> "yet another string" (and another)
a[1]: RANDOM-WORD3
a[2]: ==>
a[3]: yet another string
a[4]: and another
```